# Equivalent of pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_wait in the linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads

What is the equivalent of `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_cond_wait` in the linux kernel. and how to use them. Could you please provide simple (hello world) examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the mutex (as Als said ):

`mutex_lock()` and `mutex_unlock()` and we should init the mutex before we use it with `mutex_init()`   (from `#include <linux/mutex.h>`)

- For the equivalent of `pthread_cond_wait`

`wait_event_interruptible()` and `wake_up_interruptible()` and we should init the wait_queue_head with `init_waitqueue_head()` (from  `#include <linux/wait.h>`)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use any library calls in the kernel space because the kernel modules directly link to kernel.

You can use:

`mutex_lock()` & `mutex_unlock()`

They are provided through: **[linux/mutex.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.1/include/linux/mutex.h)**

Comment: how to make kernel module waiting condition from other module. I m looking for the equivalent of pthread_cond_wait

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: You will need something like an [Wait Queue](http://people.netfilter.org/rusty/unreliable-guides/kernel-hacking/queues.html) to do so

Answer (score 2):

I made a mutexes and conditions library for Linux kernel programming long ago (1999-ish) and used in on various projects since.

I called it LMC (linux mutexes and condition variables). This was before there was a mutex type in the kernel.

http://www.kylheku.com/~kaz/lmc.html

Recently, I added a cool new function whose semantics is "give up mutex to wait on a condition variable, **and** at the same time poll multiple file descriptors, up to a given timeout."

I used this inside kernel thread that monitored various shared objects for updates, and which communicated with kernel sockets at the same time.

Check it out:

```
/**
 * Atomically give up the mutex and wait on the condition variable.
 * Wake up if the specified timeout elapses, or if a signal is delivered.
 * Additionally, also wait on the specified file descriptors to become
 * ready, combining condition waiting with poll().
 * KCOND_WAIT_SUCCESS means the condition was signaled, or one or more
 * file descriptors are ready.
 * Also, a negative value can be returned indicating an error!
 * (The poll needs to dynamically allocate some memory for the wait table).
 * The timeout is relative to the current time, specifying how long to sleep in
 * jiffies (CPU clock ticks).
 */
int kcond_timed_wait_rel_poll(kcond_t *, kmutex_t *, long, 
                              kcond_poll_t *, unsigned int);
```

The array of `kcond_poll_t` structures is something you have to create and fill in your self, and the structure looks like this. There is a type field so you can wait for either sockets (`struct socket *`) or files (`struct file *`):

```
/**
 * Structure for file-descriptor polling condition waits.
 * This resembles struct pollfd, but uses a direct file descriptor
 * pointer rather than a file descriptor number.  Also,
 * it contains the wait queue by which the process is enqueued
 * to wait on that descriptor. Thus our poll function doesn't
 * have to dynamically allocate wait queue tables. It gets
 * them from this array! (But this means that the array cannot
 * be used by multiple threads at the same time to do polling!)
 */
typedef struct {
        kcond_poll_type_t type;  /* Must set this. */
        union {                 /* Must set union field according to type. */
                struct file *file;      
                struct socket *sock;
        } obj;
        short events;           /* And this. */
        short revents;          /* Check response in this. */
        wait_queue_t wait;          /* Internal, don't set. */
        wait_queue_head_t *queue;   /* Internal, don't set */
} kcond_poll_t;
```